# Where do I get the Kerio toolbar for Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, kerio

A friend of mine is using Kerio Connect to sync Outlook 2003 but is missing the Kerio toolbar, where you can mark spam or (more importantly) set up an out-of-office reply.

Where can I get this toolbar? Is it a separate download? It does not seem to be installed even though Kerio itself is running on the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search on their site brought me to this article on the [missing spam/not spam buttons](http://support.kerio.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=183), however if that doesn't work, one of the comments on that page say the solution in the  article about the [crashing problem](http://support.kerio.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=292) fixed it for them, perhaps it will for your friend.

Comment: Ah, and I was always searching for the missing out-of-office-button and did not find this - thanks a lot for helping a blind, I'll sure mark this as answer as soon as I tried the solution!

Comment: Ah yes, the Add-on was deactivaed - Going into Help > about Office > deactivated add-ons I was able to activate it again.